# Auditing and versioning through Entity Framework

Tags: open-source, library, software-development, c#, asp.net

Auditing and versioning database transactions is an important thing to track What's the sequence of actions? Who made these actions? and How to rollback to the previous state?

A long time ago, we used ADO.NET to interact with our databases (Informix, Sql Server, Oracle) and we audit the transaction through the database itself.

Now we use [Entity Framework 6](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa937723(v=vs.113).aspx) to interact with the databases, and we want to keep track of the transactions.

I googled about auditing and versioning through Entity Framework and have found many APIs and articles concerning how to implement them but I feel confused about stability and extensible.

**My main requirements** :

- Auditing & Versioning the main operations (`INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE`).
- Works With [Code First](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj193542(v=vs.113).aspx) & [DB First (EDMX)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj206878(v=vs.113).aspx) .
- Can audit (Oracle, SQL Server) DBMS.
- Can Include and Exclude entities.
- Can audit a [DB Graph](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/EntityFramework5/update-entity-graph-using-dbcontext.aspx).

---

Some **search results** I have found:

- [Entity Framework Plus](http://entityframework-plus.net/)
- [Tracker-enabled-dbcontext](https://github.com/bilal-fazlani/tracker-enabled-dbcontext)
- [Entity Framework Auditing](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework.Auditing/)

Comment: Would you mind detailing what you like and don't like in the feature list of each of your search results? Thanks! :-)

Comment: @NicolasRaoul : Thanks Nicolas, i'm not expert and i don't try them but i ask if any one try any of them or any other APIs to help me select the suitable one

Comment: https://github.com/bilal-fazlani/tracker-enabled-dbcontext